# How do I turn javascript loading off when using URLConnection?

Tags: java, javascript, networking, urlconnection

I'm looking to load the version of a site within the Noscript tags so the connection has to appear like it has Javascript disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: This question makes no sense... Unless you simulate a web browser in your Java application.

Comment: Please go into detail. JavaScript and Java are mostly orthogonal. What exactly is the "version of a site"? How can a connection "have" JavaScript, or have it "disabled", for that matter?

Comment: For example, if you load in http://thebottingnetwork.com/recaptcha/ with a URLConnection Input Stream you receive the Javascript enabled version of the HTML Source. However, if you turn off Javascript in your browser and visit the site again you'll see a completely different HTML Source - this is the one I'm looking to scan in.

Answer (score 2):

The UrlConnection will doesn't not need to do anything with the noscript tag, in fact it can't. UrlConnection just gets the content, it doesn't try to parse it and do anything with JS/HTML, etc. It's just text data as far as it cares.

When the noscript comes into play is when you go to render the content.

Re your comment to your question - when you disable JS and go to that URL you're still getting the same content as when you requested the URL with JS on. If you look at the HTTP response in something like firebug you'll see it's always the same. It's the rendering engine that is doing something different, so you need to look at where your app renders the content and see if you can disable JS there.

Answer (score 0):

Download the page, parse it, and look for an iframe like this:

```
<iframe
src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=6LcQ8gUAAAAAAHGMy5-aJPjhxidK2lV1KLGyJYfO"
height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Load the URL specified in the `src` attribute to get to the noscript version.